# Time Complexity Analysis of a Minimum Bottleneck Tree Algorithm

Tags: minimum-spanning-tree

The following is the solution to an exercise in the book CLRS.

The question: Give a linear-time algorithm that given a graph G and an integer b, determines whether the value of the bottleneck spanning tree is at most b.

The algorithm:

To do this, we first process the entire graph, and remove any edges that have weight greater than b. If the remaining graph is connected, we can just arbitrarily select any tree in it, and it will be a bottleneck spanning tree of weight at most b. Testing connectivity of a graph can be done in linear time by running a breadth first search and then making sure that no vertices remain white at the end.

I don't understand why the following algorithm runs in linear time. Creating a minimum spanning tree out of a graph takes at least m*log n with Prim or Kruskal (which are the only algorithms on the topic discussed in the book at that point). So does the time to create the spanning tree not count because of the phrasing of the question, and if so is there a linear time algorithm to solve this problem even
taking into account the time for making a minimum spanning tree?

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Good of you to state the where you encountered the problem. You can make quoted parts easier to identify: mark them in the post editor and use the `”` in its tool bar. [Where does the algorithm presented come from?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) (I don't see an algorithm *following* the sentence containing *following* - *preceding* or *above*?)

Comment: Please ask *one* question per question post and post a new question for the follow-up. You can use "the address behind the `Share` button" to hyperlink to a post.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody said anything about a minimum spanning tree. Since you are looking for a bottleneck spanning tree with cost $b$, you only need a tree with edges that have weight $\le b$. You can construct such a tree using $BFS$ for example, and you don't need $Kruskal$ or $Prim$ to compute it (also, they compute the *standard* minimal spanning tree, not the minimal bottleneck spanning tree).